# How do I get a list of possible windows service statuses?

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm working on a powershell script to uninstall windows service. I would like it to handle the most (if not all) possible scenarios. One thing I would like to check before I attempt to uninstall the service is service status.

I was not able to find a complete list of possible statuses that a windows service can have.

Apart from obvious ones (Stopped/Running/Stopping) are there any relevant statuses I should handle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get these by using the enum `GetNames` method on the `System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus` type:

```
[enum]::GetNames([System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus])
```

Returns:

```
Stopped
StartPending
StopPending
Running
ContinuePending
PausePending
Paused
```